# Do spellblast spells follow the target?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

One of the player of my group asked if he can use antimagic field with spellblast, and checking on the internet we found out it's possible. Then another question came out.

> **Spellblast (Sp):** This invocation (Lesser; 4th; Eldritch Essence),
>   learned at 3rd level, allows you to place an arcane spell that affects
>   an area upon your eldritch blast. **If the eldritch blast hits its
>   target, the spell's area is centered on any corner of the target's
>   space, even if the spell could normally be centered only on the
>   caster.** If the eldritch blast misses its target, the spell is lost
>   with no effect.
>
> It takes a full-round action to cast the spell and fire the eldritch
>   blast. Only an area spell with a casting time no greater than 1
>   standard action can be placed upon your eldritch blast.
>
> Only the first target of your eldritch blast is affected by the spell
>   (for example, an eldritch chain spellblast centers the spell on the
>   initial target, not on any of the secondary targets). If your eldritch
>   blast doesn't specify a target, you can't apply this invocation to the
>   blast.
>
> Treat spellblast as a spell whose level is equal to the area spell
>   placed upon the eldritch blast (minimum 4th level).

I'm not sure what the bold part means. If i cast a emanation spell usually centered on the caster (or another target) will it be "attached" to the target or to a point occupied by the target? That is, if the target moves will the AMF move too?

Comment: *And* if a big enough creature is hit and the effect is attached, can the creature be part-way in and part-way out of the emanation? *Yuck!* [Take that, point of origin!](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117568/8610)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the spell's area is centered on any corner of the target's space

Seems pretty clear that the spell is centered on a point in  space, not on the target of the eldritch blast.

Comment: +1. It may be worth comparing this wording to the arcane archer’s imbue arrow, which says the spell is centered on the arrow—if that’s embedded in the target, well...